# Excel Dropdown List from Range + One Static Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

Id like to create a DropDown list from a Named Range containing all months in the year, but also id like to add a static value at the beginning of the list called "All" im wondering if that's possible!

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the problem?

Comment: Tried using INDIRECT and & when setting the list source but didnt work, i have no idea what else to try, i know i could add a row to the table containing the months but that would make it dirty and i couldnt reuse same named range for places where i dont want the All option to be available

Comment: Have you tried adding the value you want to be able to choose from to the list in the named range?

Comment: Use one list and two overlapping named ranges (one for the months and the other for "All" + the months)

Comment: @DSB,, use dependent drop down with 2 list ,, 1st list Month name & 2nd should ALL & Months,, and let me remind every value itself is static,, but never the list is !!